# Magento2 Newsletter grid custom column filter not working

Tags: magento2, rest-api, newsletter

I have added some custom columns in newsletter grid but unfortunately filter is not working for my custom columns in grid, can anyone let me know what could be issue or something i am missing to add? when i filter with custom column, nothing filters.

Here is the code i have done so far,this is code of newsletter_subscriber_block.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="adminhtml.newslettrer.subscriber.grid.columnSet">
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Urgency</argument>
                    <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">urgency</argument>
                    <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">options</argument>
                    <argument name="options" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="withinweek" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">With in 3 Weeks</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="afterweek" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">After 3 Weeks</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                    <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-urgency</argument>
                    <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-urgency</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

I have override existing newsletter grid layout xml and put custom column code like above code explained.

Comment: add code what you have tried so far

Comment: I have override newsletter_subscriber_block.xml in my custom module layout and added column code like one in existing newsletter grid. i cannot put whole code because of characters limitation in this textarea.

Comment: Add in your question not in comment, you can edit your question

Comment: ok please check my question i have edited

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala ,any success about my question?

Comment: add a code not screenshot

Comment: Please check now.

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala, did you find any solution for me upon this?

Comment: @bhargavshastri Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @prachi, Nope i couldn't

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because "filter_index" missing in the above code.
I added a new column "created_at" inside the "newsletter_subscriber" table and also added it inside the newsletter subscriber grid inside the admin panel with the below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="adminhtml.newslettrer.subscriber.grid.columnSet">
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" name="adminhtml.newslettrer.subscriber.grid.columnSet.created_at" as="created_at">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">First subscription date</argument>
                    <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">datetime</argument>
                    <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">created_at</argument>
                    <argument name="filter_index" xsi:type="string">main_table.created_at</argument>
                    <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">created_at</argument>
                    <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-period</argument>
                    <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-period</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

As you can see above I added the "filter_index" argument with the value "main_table.created_at" and it's resolved the filter issue of the newly added grid column.
So you need to add a new argument as below to resolve your issue.

```
<argument name="filter_index" xsi:type="string">main_table.urgency</argument>
```